# Concourse fly connecting to localhost instead of remote server

Tags: concourse

Running concourse on GCP with an exposed endpoint.  When I try to do a "fly execute" I get the following:

```
executing build 1160 at http://99.999.999.99:8080/builds/1160
upload request failed: Put http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/pipes/ccd4664e-99a9-44bd-4de8-d47c7c012fa8:
    dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: getsockopt: connection refused
```

Don't understand why it's trying to upload to a local loopback.  I logged into the remote successfully with "fly login"

Comment: what happens if you run `fly targets`?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Turns out I had to set the CONCOURSE_EXTERNAL_URL environment variable on the web application and it fixed it.

I got help on the GitHub issue here: https://github.com/concourse/concourse/issues/2080#issuecomment-372003581